# Should the phrase "if I were president" be enclosed by commas?

Tags: commas

> That's why if I were president, I would declare war against France.

> That's why if I were president I would declare war against France.

Do you put a comma or not here, I thought you needed a comma here, but because of the "That's why" I am not sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this article](https://owl.purdue.edu/owl/general_writing/punctuation/commas/extended_rules_for_commas.html), non-essential clauses in the middle of a sentence should be enclosed in commas.

> That's why, if I were president, I would declare war against France.

While "if I were president" is important to get a complete picture of what the writer means, it is not essential to the understanding of the sentence that it is enclosed in. You can demonstrate this by removing it completely:

> That's why I would declare war against France